# Reseting p:ajax drop down after un-selecting option

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using prime faces in my project. I am generating a pull down by using p:ajax and its working fine for me. But i have notice a problem that is if i select ---select one-- my pull down which i have generated by p:ajax is not resetting to default .

My code is:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="propExam" value="#{rollNoBean.examination}" 
                                    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" editable="false"
                                    required="true" label="Examination Applied For" styleClass="dropdownWidth">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="---Select One---" itemValue="0" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{rollNoBean.testExamNames}" var="test" itemLabel="#{test.name}" itemValue="#{test}" noSelectionOption="true" />

                                     <p:ajax   listener="#{rollNoBean.readFilterByExamination(rollNoBean.examination.id)}" 
                                    update="degreeList centerId"  />

                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <h:outputText value="Select Filter Category :" />

                            <p:selectOneMenu id="degreeList"
                                value="#{rollNoBean.filter}" editable="false"
                                converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" required="true"
                                label="Please Select degree" styleClass="dropdownWidth">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="---Select One---" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{rollNoBean.degreeNames}"
                                var="degree" itemLabel="#{degree.name}" itemValue="#{degree}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

and my bean code is:

```
public List<Filter> readFilterByExamination(int id)
{
    if(id!=0)
    {
    return degreeNames=examinationDetailsService.readFilterByExamination(id);    
    }
    return degreeNames=new ArrayList<Filter>();

}
```

Please give suggetion

Comment: please check my code

Comment: What is the default value ?

Comment: Since #{rollNoBean.examination} is an object, itemValue="0" cannot convert to that object.

Comment: my default value is 0.